# How can I show all work items in azure devops work items screen

Tags: azure, azure-devops

So by default when I go into my azure devops work items for particular project it has around 7 pre-defined options shown in image below, for example recently created shows last 30 days. I find it really frustrating that there is no option to view all work items in here, as i would be nice to be able to search first and make sure duplicate items don't get logged. I have did some searching and the only work around seems to be to create a query which is a bit cumbersome.

Surely there is another way to achieve this in the work items screen ? Thanks for any help

[image: Work items]

Comment: _Recently updated_ option seems to display quite old work items despite its name. On my project it displays items that have 2 years old. Did you try it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I show all work items in azure devops work items screen

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed**. There is no way to fix it at present.

As we know, those 7 pre-defined options use the cache mechanism, which will keep the last option used last.

Just like the last time we used the option **Assigned to me**, then the next time we click on **Work items**, it will show **Assigned to me** by default. This can bring us convenience according to our usage habits.

So, if we add the option for **All Work items** in the Work items screen, this will greatly increase the burden of Azure devops and make the response of Azure devops slow or even crash. That because work items serve the entire org, usually all work items will be a large number.

To get the all Work items, we have to create a query and save this query, you just need to run that query when you check the duplicate items instead of creating it every time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it would be a nice feature all the same

Comment: Whoever made this decision is woefully technically uninformed. If users are asking for a feature, but you say "No, this is by design" - then quite simply the product hasn't been designed around its users.

Comment: One of the cons of SaaS. App designers consider the compute cost of feature, not just usefulness to users.

Comment: I create a bunch of items for my team, I want to view them all to see progress. I cannot do so, without having to create a query which require a fair amount of prerequisite knowledge. The slowness of the experience is not fair on any of the team. P.s. perhaps you need some paging for that big query ;-)

Comment: Yeah, this is bad and should be fixed. I always end up having to make queries on the fly. Very annoying since the boards are also useless.

Comment: "This behavior is ***poorly*** designed." Fixed it for you :)

Comment: This makes no sense. DevOps will potentially crash? Why would you grab all items from the org if I'm in a single project?

Comment: "...response of Azure devops slow or even crash" this reasoning is hilarious. Just fix your bugs

Comment: If you can make a query to do the same thing without it running too slow or crashing, why not have it as an available option in the dropdown?

Comment: Reminds me of the 1990s where many valid bug reports of a certain company would be answered by "This is not a bug, it's a feature". That being said, be a bit careful because @LeoLiu is not the official representative of a company.

Answer (score 8):

More of a workaround than an answer, but:

```
Select Azure DevOps / Boards / Work Items / Recently Created

Open in queries
Editor
Amend or remove selection criteria
Save Query
```

Then to run that query:

```
Azure DevOps / Boards / Open in queries 
Click Queries at the top
Select the query you saved
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to the backlog, all items will be there and you can toggle completed items on/off

Comment: Unparented Tasks are not displayed there.

Answer (score -2):

If you select EPICS in the Backlog view, then expand the list fully (from the + and - at the top left) you will see ALL open and closed Features, User Stories and Tasks.

This will work if you do NOT close an Epic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).